# Update visual of element that uses a Static property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm using `SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor` to change the `Foreground` of a bunch of `TabItems`, but wpf can't detect the color changes with that static value.

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" 
        Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor}, 
        Converter={StaticResource WindowColorToForegroundConverter}}"/>
```

The converter detects if the color is darker or brighter and returns a inverted brightness brush. Also if the W10 machine has the setting `Show Color on Start, Taskbar, Action Center` turned off (via registry).

I can detect when the color changes via `SystemParameters.StaticPropertyChanged`, but I couldn't update the `Foreground`.

How could I make my app aware of changes in the window color?
or
How can I update the visual of my `TabItems`?

Comment: You can create a new property for the purpose of binding, which you explicitly set in your `StaticPropertyChanged` event handler, or you could use the [`BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the event handler. Either should work fine. What have you _tried_? If you still need help, please provide a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, with an explanation of what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: The post contains everything that I tried so far. I don't know how to proceed. I don't know how to update the Foreground based on a `Static` value that don't update by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it!

My goal was to update the style of my `TabItems` based on the current window title/chrome color, but since the `Static` property wasn't triggering my `Triggers`, I had to do it by code.

Since my app can extend the chrome into the client area, some `Labels` may be difficult to read while the window color is dark.

This is the result of my work:

Light:
[image: Light Theme]

Dark:
[image: Dark Theme]

Here's how:

I detect the window color changes by using `StaticPropertyChanged`:

```
private void SystemParameters_StaticPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "WindowGlassColor")
    {
        RibbonTabControl.UpdateVisual();
    }
}
```

I had to create a custom `TabItem` control with a single boolean property called `IsDark`.

My `TabControl` has a public method to update the `IsDark` value:

```
public void UpdateVisual()
{
    //If glass isn't enabled, ignore.
    var isDark = !SystemParameters.IsGlassEnabled 
           //Gets a registry value. See below.
        || !Glass.UsesColor 
           //Color threshold. See below.   
        || SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor.GetBrightness() < 137; 

    //Manually update the IsDark property.
    foreach (var tab in _tabPanel.Children.OfType<AwareTabItem>())
    {
        tab.IsDark = isDark;
    }
}
```

Gets if the `Show Color on Start, Taskbar, Action Center` is checked:

```
public static bool UsesColor
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            //Start menu: 
            //HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\
            //CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize
            var autoColorization = 
                Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM", 
                    "ColorPrevalence", "0").ToString();

            return autoColorization.Equals("1");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Gets the brightness value of a give `Color`:

```
public static int GetBrightness(this Color c)
{
    //I discovered that 137 is the threshold, if more than that,
    //the window title is white. Less than that, is black.
    return (int)Math.Sqrt(
        c.R * c.R * .241 +
        c.G * c.G * .691 +
        c.B * c.B * .068);
}
```

And finally, here's my `AwareTabItem` `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AwareTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AwareTabItem}">
                <Grid Name="Panel" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D4" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" Effect="{x:Null}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header" Margin="10,2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="Panel">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2B579A" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2B579A" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, !IsDark, !IsSelected-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelect}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>

                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#9AFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#90FFFFFF" Offset="0.4"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, !IsDark, IsMouseOver-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2B579A"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, !IsDark, IsSelected-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2B579A" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, IsDark, !IsSelected-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF8F8FF"/>

                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor}, 
                                                  Converter={StaticResource ColorToAlphaConverter}, ConverterParameter=6E}" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor}, 
                                                  Converter={StaticResource ColorToAlphaConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}" Offset="0.4"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, IsDark, IsMouseOver-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBFEFFF"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>

                    <!--When ExtendChrome, IsDark, IsSelected-->
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=EditorExtendChrome, FallbackValue=False}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDark}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2B579A" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!--Default Values-->
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semilight"/>
</Style>
```

I've noticed that when using a dark window color, the black `RadialGradientBrush` had a strange effect, so I'm using the actual window color to make a soft background (to improve readability when the window is too transparent). And to use a `GradientStop` I had to create a `Converter` that takes the current window color and applies the given parameter as the alpha value.

ColorToAlpha converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var color = value as Color?;
    var alphaAux = parameter as string;

    if (!color.HasValue)
        return value;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(alphaAux))
        return value;

    int alpha = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(alphaAux, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out alpha))
        return value;

    return Color.FromArgb((byte)alpha, color.Value.R, color.Value.G, color.Value.B);
}
```